# How to setup the optimiser to maximize expected portfolio return subject to volatility constraint?

Tags: r, optimization, solver, portfolio, quantitative-finance

I have a time series of buy and sell signals for 6 securities. I am attempting to solve for the portfolio weights that would maximize the signal strength subject to a target volatility of 15%.

The portfolio has the following constraints. Less than 175% long, less than 75% short, and positions must be between 100% and -100% of the unlevered portfolio.

I have been able to find a solver to maximize the signal strength, but I can't figure out how to add the target volatility constraint using the covariance matrix of the asset return streams. Below is the setup, with signals being the frame like object of buy/sell signals. **`df`** is the data frame of return streams.

```
library(quadprog)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)



signals <- structure(list( SPY = c(0, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -1, -1),
                           FXY = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1),
                           FXE = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ),
                           GLD = c(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5),
                           JJC = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1),
                           TLT = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                           ),
                    .Names     = c("SPY", "FXY", "FXE", "GLD", "JJC", "TLT"),
                     row.names = c("2016-01-08", "2016-01-11", "2016-01-12", "2016-01-13", "2016-01-14", "2016-01-15", "2016-01-19"),
                     class     = "data.frame"
                     )

#list of ETF symbols representing (snp, jpy, euro, gold, copper, long treasury)
symbollist <- c("SPY", "FXY", "FXE", "GLD", "JJC", "TLT")

#call symbols dating back from 2010
getSymbols(symbollist, from="2015-01-01")

#bind column function
badj <- function(x){
merge(
dailyReturn(x)
)
}

tickers <- list(SPY, FXY, FXE, GLD, JJC, TLT)

sigma <- cov(df)

df <- as.data.frame(lapply(tickers, badj))
colnames(df) <- symbollist

sigma <- cov(df)
```

Here is what I have so far in terms of optimizing

```
#create portfolio object
port <- portfolio.spec( assets    = symbollist )
#add constraints
port <- add.constraint( portfolio = port,
                        type      = "box",
                        min       = c(-1),
                        max       = c(1)
                        )

port <- add.constraint( portfolio = port,
                        type      = "weight_sum",
                        min_sum   = -.75,
                        max_sum   = 1.75
                        )
#add objective
port <- add.objective(  portfolio = port,
                        type      = "return",
                        name      = "mean"
                        )

#optimize
max_port <- optimize.portfolio( signals[nrow(signals),]
                                portfolio       = port,
                                optimize_method = "ROI",
                                trace           = TRUE
                                )

print(max_port)
```

I suspect this is a relatively easy fix, and is just a matter of figuring out the right optimizer or mechanics to use but I'm really stuck, thanks for any guidance you can offer!

Comment: I'm not really sure how this this a **programming question.** It seems like you want someone to do your research for you, not like you have a **specific** programming question. Can you please clarify / simplify your question?

Comment: I cannot figure out how to set up the PortfolioAnalytics package to optimize based on my objectives, I know this can be done in Excel Solver, and is a fairly routine operation. Despite this, I can't find any resources explaining how to set it up for 'R'. My question therefore can be answered in one of two ways, either someone who understands how to use Portfolio Analytics can explain what I'm missing in my code, or point me towards a better package.